# Modal Popup not refreshing Parent Page

Tags: c#, modalpopupextender

I know this will seem vague and I will work on getting some code posted but wanted to get some initial feedback to see if anyone else has experienced this problem. I have a page with a listbox and a button. When I click the button a modal popup displays a checkbox list that allows the user to select options. At the bottom of the popup I have a "OK" and "CANCEL" button. If the user clicks "OK", the items are saved that the user has selected in the checkbox list, but the parent page does not refresh. I had the parent page refreshing and the listbox displaying the choices made on the modal popup. This is happening only part of the time and appears to be on IE8, although I am running IE8, with and without compatibility, and not experiencing this issue. I have tried running on IE7 and don't see the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you making the parent page refresh hen closing the popup? You must have added something specifically to do this because this would not be befault behaviour. Can you post the code?

Comment: We're gonna need to see the code.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you are looking for but should solve your problem if it is working in ie 7.  Add this to the page and it will force ie8 to render the page as ie7.

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />`